# Is there a Dojo calendar similar to the JQuery plugin FullCalendar?

Tags: dojo, calendar

I'm looking a Dojo based calendar that can display events spanning across days in a month view exactly like the JQuery plugin [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

I work primarily in Dojo and I don't want to load JQuery if I don't need to.

Comment: I was just searching for the exact same thing. I was surprised to find that you had asked this just a few hours ago. I love Dojo and hope we can find something similar to FullCalendar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This thread is a bit old now but I wanted to raise that there's now a candidate widget written by me for dojo 1.8+ that does exactly what you need: https://github.com/damiengarbarino/dojo-calendar

I tried to use the dojoc project and finally developed my own widget.

It is heavily customizable, has mouse, keyboard and even touch support, right to left display support, date formatting, custom views etc.

Documentation is available at: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/calendar

Comment: Looks fantastic! This was much needed. Thanks Damien.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for something similiar recently and the best I can find is the 'dojoc' library.  It appears to have been apart of the full dojotoolkit at some point but I can't seem to find a whole lot of information on it.

A test page showing it is on the author's website [here](http://unscriptable.com/code/dojocal/dojocalTest.html).  The github page for it is [here](https://github.com/hflw/dojo-cal).  So far my attempts to locally use it have failed miserably.  It seems to be built against an older version of dojo as well since it hasn't been updated in a while.

Comment: Nice find. It looks promising but the code hasn't been updated in over a year so it might need some work. I'll give it shot and see what happens.

Comment: That's kind of what I expected,but I figured it was better to share the discovery regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Although the Dojo 1.8 calendar widget looks promising, the documentation linked here http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/calendar is not up to scratch. Possibly the widget itself is also not ready for general use.

For example, it is proving difficult to prevent a particular event from being edited.

I realise 1.8 is not out yet. I trust the calendar widget and documentation will be better by the time 1.8 is released.